# javax.mail.internet.ParseException: In Content-Type string , expected '/', got :

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, multipartform-data

I want to implement mail with attached file using JSF. I tried this code:

```
private Part file;

    private String sendFromGMail(String from, String pass, String[] to, String subject, String body)
    {
        String status;

        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        try
        {
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];

            // To get the array of addresses
            for (int i = 0; i < to.length; i++)
            {
                toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < toAddress.length; i++)
            {
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
            }

            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(body);

            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(file, file.getName()));
            messageBodyPart.setFileName(file.getName());
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            message.setContent(multipart);

            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(host, from, pass);
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
        }
        catch (AddressException ae)
        {
            ae.printStackTrace();
            return status = "Cannot send Message!";
        }
        catch (MessagingException me)
        {
            me.printStackTrace();
            return status = "Cannot send Message!";
        }

        return status = "Message is send!";
    }

    //.......................

    public Part getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(Part file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public void upload() {

        if (file != null) {


            try (InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream(); FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("D:" + File.separator + "files" + File.separator + file.getSubmittedFileName())) {

                int bytesRead = 0;
                final byte[] chunck = new byte[1024];
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(chunck)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(chunck, 0, bytesRead);
                }

                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Upload successfully ended!"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Upload failed!"));
            }
        }
    }
```

But in Tomcat log file I get this error:

```
javax.mail.internet.ParseException: In Content-Type string <form:fileToUpload>, expected '/', got :
    at javax.mail.internet.ContentType.<init>(ContentType.java:103)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1448)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders(MimeMessage.java:2190)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.saveChanges(MimeMessage.java:2151)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1846)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1196)
    at com.web.common.Contacts.sendFromGMail(Contacts.java:135)
    at com.web.common.Contacts.sendEmail(Contacts.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is there any solution of this problem?

In my case I want to upload file using `h:inputFile` and send it as e-mail attachment. But I get error.

Comment: Did you compare got the code from here http://kahimyang.info/kauswagan/code-blogs/536/a-java-class-for-sending-multipart-email-messages-through-your-gmail-account

Comment: Ok, but this code uses `String []attachments`. in my case I have binary file.

Comment: two more resources that can guide you https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home and http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html

Comment: @MauricioGracia This exception is very specific, documentation can't help.

Comment: so you are telling me that in the samples link is not a single sample sending a multipart email ?

Comment: Emails cannot be sent using JSF. Besides, the exception stack-trace does not relate anything to JSF. You had better remove the JSF nuisance.

Comment: That's right, this is not a JSF problem. Try to get your code working in a `main` method before you bother integrating with JSF.

Comment: what is the value of messsae.getContentType() ?

Comment: @MauricioGracia no idea

Comment: @PeterPenzov how about a break point or printing/showing the value in the console ;-)

Comment: @MauricioGracia I found the problem. I need help for this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30810014/javax-servlet-http-part-to-java-io-file Can you give a hand please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Didn't I already answer this somewhere else?

Use Part.getInputStream() with a [ByteArrayDataSource](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/util/ByteArrayDataSource.html#ByteArrayDataSource(java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String)):

```
ByteArrayDataSource ds = new ByteArrayDataSource(file.getInputStream(), file.getContentType());
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));
```